# Crystal Reports compare does not work without trim

Tags: select, crystal-reports, logic

{AR_Customer.CustomerType} is a 4 character field

{AR_Customer.CustomerType}<>"S"
does not return all records where this is true unless I do it this way:
trim({AR_Customer.CustomerType})<>"S"

in the actual database the NULL fields are the ones I'm missing.

So this tells me than NULL is the same as "S" -- I don't think so, but that's how Crystal is reacting without trim()

Is there a general rule here that I need to understand?

Comment: What database are you using? Is "S" being stored as "S "(with 3 spaces after it)?

Comment: Is the 'Convert Database NULL values to default' property enabled for report (File | Report Options...) or workstation (File | Options...)?

Answer (score 0):

The database column could be a "fixed width" of 4 characters, if that is true then `{AR_Customer.CustomerType}<>"S   "` would be an alternative to `trim({AR_Customer.CustomerType})<>"S"` which woks because it strips away white space of the field.

NULL does **NOT** equal 'S' or any value at all. In fact in SQL you cannot use he equal symbol for NULL, instead you have to use these special terms:

```
IS NULL
IS NOT NULL
```

In the database, using SQL, a query to get all rows with AR_Customer.CustomerType of "S" and NULLs too would be:

```
where (AR_Customer.CustomerType = 'S   ' or AR_Customer.CustomerType IS NULL)
```